# Meaning of "de más"

Tags: definiciones, modismos

I cannot find meaning of "de más" in dictionary. Trying to translate this sentence:

> Y lo que opinen los demás está **de más**

What is the meaning?
It is from the [song of Mecano - Mujer Contra Mujer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wVSA2CEIQ7U), if you need more context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [RAE](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Cbumyr3WLD6Afn24Wr):

> 1.10. **de más**. [...] Locución adverbial que significa ‘de sobra, en demasía’: «Las cosas se amontonan... porque sobran... hay de más» (Pavlovsky Pablo [Arg. 1987]). Forma parte, asimismo, de locuciones verbales como *hablar de más* (‘decir cosas inconvenientes’): «Uno de los conjurados habló de más» (Clarín [Arg.] 17.2.97); y ***estar de más*** (‘sobrar o estorbar’): «Bibi estaba de más en su vida» (Contreras Nadador [Chile 1995]). En todos estos casos se escribe en dos palabras. No debe confundirse con *demás* (‘(lo) restante’; → [demás](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=F6EAJxg3MD6nqBy21x)).

As RAE explains, "de más" generally means to be "left" or "left over", sometimes referring to an excess of something.

- Hay un plato *de más* por si viene una visita inesperada = There's a spare dish just in case we have  unexpected guests.

In the expression "estar de más", it means to "bother" or "disturb", generally used as an innuendo:

- Estás *de más* aquí = You're bothering here (you shouldn't be here).

In this case, the author is saying that everything people may say will just bother/upset him or her, thus emphasizing the pointlessness of paying attention to gossip.

Comment: Yay, thanks. Re your last paragraph: so is she saying that it will bother/upset her or that it just doesn't mean anything to her? Because there are two very different things!!

Comment: @Tomas I think *estás **de más** aquí* can be often taken in different ways: the one that Yay exposed and something like *you don't belong here.* (Either you're upsetting people or you weren't invited.)

Comment: Tomas: The singer just says people is upsetting her with their gossiping, but that she won't pay attention to them, which doesn't necessarily mean it means nothing to her. It may or may not. The expression "tus comentarios están de más" is generally used to tell someone they aren't contributing in any way to a conversation and that they are being rude/bothering/upsetting, but not that what they are saying doesn't mean anything to anybody. So I'd say it's a yes to the first thing.

Answer (score 5):

*está de más = sobra*. (It's unnecessary.)

Other examples include:

> 1. ***está de más*** decir que... = **es innecesario** decir que...
> 2. — llevaré las maletas.
>      — pero ***está de más*** hacer eso = pero ***es innecesario*** hacer eso.